# Convert reStructuredText to plain text programmatically in Python

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

Say I have some reStructuredText source in a string

```
source = """
============
Introduction
============

Hello world.

.. code-block:: bash

    $ echo Greetings.


"""

import sys

import docutils.nodes
import docutils.parsers.rst
import docutils.utils
import sphinx.writers.text
import sphinx.builders.text

def parse_rst(text: str) -> docutils.nodes.document:
    parser = docutils.parsers.rst.Parser()
    components = (docutils.parsers.rst.Parser,)
    settings = docutils.frontend.OptionParser(components=components).get_default_values()
    document = docutils.utils.new_document('<rst-doc>', settings=settings)
    parser.parse(text, document)
    return document

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    document = parse_rst(source)
```

I'd like to convert it into plain text without the reST markup using Python.

I tried to use [`sphinx.builders.text.TextBuilder`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.text.TextBuilder) but it seems to want an `App` object, not a string.

---

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192632/how-to-convert-restructuredtext-to-plain-text) is a related question about doing it manually on the command-line with files instead of strings.
- Parsing code comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48719723/3346095)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works. It has some hacks like setting a fake config dir, maybe there's a better way.

```
import sys
import textwrap
import types

import docutils.nodes
import docutils.parsers.rst
import docutils.utils
import sphinx.writers.text
import sphinx.builders.text
import sphinx.util.osutil


def parse_rst(text: str) -> docutils.nodes.document:
    parser = docutils.parsers.rst.Parser()
    components = (docutils.parsers.rst.Parser,)
    settings = docutils.frontend.OptionParser(
        components=components
    ).get_default_values()
    document = docutils.utils.new_document("<rst-doc>", settings=settings)
    parser.parse(text, document)
    return document


if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = textwrap.dedent(
        """\
    ============
    Introduction
    ============

    Hello world.

    .. code-block:: bash

        $ echo Greetings.


    """
    )

    document = parse_rst(source)

    app = types.SimpleNamespace(
        srcdir=None,
        confdir=None,
        outdir=None,
        doctreedir="/",
        config=types.SimpleNamespace(
            text_newlines="native",
            text_sectionchars="=",
            text_add_secnumbers=False,
            text_secnumber_suffix=".",
        ),
        tags=set(),
        registry=types.SimpleNamespace(
            create_translator=lambda self, something, new_builder: sphinx.writers.text.TextTranslator(
                document, new_builder
            )
        ),
    )

    builder = sphinx.builders.text.TextBuilder(app)

    translator = sphinx.writers.text.TextTranslator(document, builder)

    document.walkabout(translator)

    print(translator.body)
```

Output:

```
    Introduction
    ============

    Hello world.

       $ echo Greetings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx comes with a [TextBuilder](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html?highlight=make#sphinx.builders.text.TextBuilder).  From the command line:

```
make text
```

Answer (score 0):

This a workaround that seems to work in Linux.
It uses linux command 'more' to do the job.

```
import subprocess


def rst_to_plain_text(rst_file: Union[str, Path], tmpfile="tmp.txt") -> str:
    """use linux command 'more' to read contents of a reStructuredText format file to string

    Args:
        rst_file (Union[str, Path]): filepath to .rst file
        tmpfile (str, optional): temporary file to write as plain text

    Returns:
        str: plain text version of rst file
    """
    subprocess.check_output(f"more {rst_file} > {tmpfile}", shell=True)
    with open(tmpfile, "r") as f:
        txt = f.read()
    return txt
```

Terveisin, Markus